# Date filter in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Filter dates that have not passed

```py
class Distributor(models.Model):
    expire_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to get the data that has not expired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from datetime import datetime


desired_query = Distributor.objects.filter(expire_at__gt=datetime.now())
```

The mentioned query in the above code snippet will return `Distributor` objects have not expired yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here the query would look like if you want the data where `expire_at` is null

```
Distributor.objects.filter(expire_at__isnull=True)
```

> `isnull()` is a method of the QuerySet class and it returns True
> if the value of the field is null.